# Make sound cut itself off rather than play over itself

Tags: java, android

My 1st app is an audio sampler. A button starts an audio loop and other buttons play different sounds over the top.

If I hit a button multiple times, the sound will play over itself.
I want the last click to cut off any audio still playing from the same button. But I don't want it to interfere with any audio started from a different button.

(For a button that plays audio of someone rapping "my name is", 3 quick clicks of the same button should result in "my-my-my name is". But a loop should remain playing in the background).

I'm using SoundPool and OnTouchListeners.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SoundPool, but with MediaPlayer, if you use release() it should stop it. If you put it before the start(), it should stop it (if it's already playing) then start it again.

EDIT

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#stop%28int%29

public final void stop (int streamID)
Since: API Level 1

Stop a playback stream. Stop the stream specified by the streamID. This is the value returned by the play() function. If the stream is playing, it will be stopped. It also releases any native resources associated with this stream. If the stream is not playing, it will have no effect.

Parameters
streamID    a streamID returned by the play() function

Have you tried calling stop(streamID)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck yet. I tried release, pause, and stop in a few spots before start. Doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: are you trying to release() etc, the soundID or thestreamID?

Comment: To be more acurate, Pause and stop don't seem to affect it. soundpool.release dissables sound from all my buttons

Comment: see my edit, stop() works on the streamID that is returned when you use play().

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `SoundPool`, the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool%28int,%20int,%20int%29) has a parameter for `maxStreams`. Also in the overview:

> When the SoundPool object is constructed, the maxStreams parameter sets the maximum number of streams that can be played at a time from this single SoundPool. SoundPool tracks the number of active streams. If the maximum number of streams is exceeded, SoundPool will automatically stop a previously playing stream based first on priority and then by age within that priority.

You could create a separate `SoundPool` (separate from the loop) for this one sound and set `maxStreams` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. I had the loop in MediaPlayer anyway so it's not affected.